# handle ruby send nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

scope :

```
class Car < ApplicationRecord
 scope :sold_between, -> (start_date, end_date,exclude_used_cars=true){

    _used = exclude_used_cars ? "exclude_used_cars" : ""

    Car.where("start_date <= ?", start_date  ).and("end_date <= ?", end_date ).send(_used)  

 }  

 scope :exclude_used_cars, -> {
        where.not(state: :used)
 }
```

Problem:

stuck with `.send(_used)`  I need to pass some valid symbols, but actually I have nil value `exclude_used_cars` when it is false.

Any better way solving this. Thanks

Comment: `where(start_date <= start_date )` is not likely to do what you want. That's `where(true)`. Do you mean `where("start_date <= ?", start_date )`? Similar issue with `and(end_date => end_date )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by using a normal `if` and taking advantage of the chaining nature of queries.

Note that your `where` clause isn't quite right. Values need to be passed in using [placeholders](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#array-conditions). While there is a [`.or`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-or) there is no `.and`. Additional `.where` calls will go together with `and`.

Also note that I've avoided hard coding the `Car` class name in the scope. This ensures it will work with subclasses.

```
 scope :sold_between, -> (start_date, end_date,exclude_used_cars=true){
    query = where(
        "start_date <= :start_date and end_date >= :end_date",
        { start_date: start_date, end_date: end_date }
    )
    if exclude_used_cars
      query = query.exclude_used_cars
    end

    query
 }
```

Because you can chain queries and scopes like this consider whether there's a need for a special `exclude_used_cars` parameter, especially one that defaults to `true`. The user of `sold_between` can as easily add the scope themselves. This is simpler and more explicit.

```
scope :sold_between, -> (start_date, end_date) {
   where(
       "start_date <= :start_date and end_date >= :end_date",
       { start_date: start_date, end_date: end_date }
   )
}  

# All cars
Cars.sold_between(start, end)

# Without used cars
Cars.sold_between(start, end).exclude_used_cars
```

Comment: brilliant @Schwern